# Find cipher suites offered by clients in TLS

Tags: grep, security, ssl, tshark

I have an assignment where I need to extract data from a pcap file. This is what the file looks like:
[image]

**The question is, Find cipher suites offered by clients in TLS.** I know that the cipher suites I am looking for is in the initial Client Hello packet, but **how do I find the cipher suites?**

This is what I have so far:

```
tshark -r assign1.pcap | grep "Client Hello"
```

and this is the output I get:
[image]

Here is the file: https://ufile.io/jsfjr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the following switches to `tshark` you can get a more detailed list of Client Hello handshaking:

```
$ tshark -r assign2.pcap -Y ssl.handshake.ciphersuites -Vx | less
```

If you search through the `less` output looking for `/Client Hello` you'll find this section:

```
SSL Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 246
    Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
        Length: 242
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Random
            gmt_unix_time: Mar 17, 2068 11:26:39.000000000 EDT
            random_bytes: 981fbf58a3116dd17c64b602e2809de75dac922eb559a0ba...
        Session ID Length: 0
        Cipher Suites Length: 108
        Cipher Suites (54 suites)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009f)
            Cipher Suite: Unknown (0xcca9)
            Cipher Suite: Unknown (0xcca8)
            Cipher Suite: Unknown (0xccaa)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009e)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x006b)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0067)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0039)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00ad)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00ab)
            Cipher Suite: Unknown (0xccae)
            Cipher Suite: Unknown (0xccad)
            Cipher Suite: Unknown (0xccac)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009d)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00a9)
            Cipher Suite: Unknown (0xccab)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00ac)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00aa)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00a8)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x003d)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003c)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc038)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc036)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0x00b7)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0x00b3)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0095)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0091)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0x00af)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x008d)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc037)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc035)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x00b6)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x00b2)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0094)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0090)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x00ae)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x008c)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)
        Compression Methods Length: 1
...
```

#### References

- [I need to determine the cipher suite being used by the VPN using wireshark](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/555308-i-need-to-determine-the-cipher-suite-being-used-by-the-vpn-using-wireshark)
- [Display Filter Reference: Secure Sockets Layer](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/s/ssl.html)
- [tshark tutorial and filter examples](https://hackertarget.com/tshark-tutorial-and-filter-examples/)
- [Decode SSL Decimal fields in tshark output](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/37528/decode-ssl-decimal-fields-in-tshark-output)

Comment: Thank you! I just needed to add a grep onto that cmd and then it works!